# PAF script in headless mode

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am running my script in headless mode and I'm hitting errors that don't occur when I run the same in Non-Headless mode. Can I execute Pace Automation Framework script in Headless mode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can execute PAF script in headless mode.
To run chrome in headless mode, following property needs to be set in init.properties file.

```
browser=Chrome  execute.headless=true
```

chrome and Firefox headless browser is available in PAF. If you want to execute script in other headless browsers, you can create custom drivers for that. PAF will support  custom drivers.